# d3.js treemap could paint internal nodes too

Tags: d3.js, treemap

This question is in regards to Mike Bostock's very exciting [d3.js library](http://d3js.org/) in general, and more specifically the treemap plot.  Note: treemap seems to have two versions, the ["talk version"](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html) and the ["example version"](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html).  My question relates to the "talk version," which has the zoom feature.

My question is more of a wish: How difficult would it be to extend treemap to accommodate and show multiple internal nodes, with multiple levels of zoom?  For example, click to go down one level and option-click to go up one level.  Perhaps to keep things tidy, only nodes one level deeper are painted -- as you zoom in, deeper levels are resolved.

This is my pie-in-the-sky wish -- I am not familiar with javascript and can't take this on right now -- but it seems do-able on a visual/UI level.  I did notice that mbostock [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011130/d3-js-treemap-just-paint-leaf-nodes) that treemap only shows leaf nodes, but I don't know if this is a design constraint or just a [SMOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming).

Anyone with any interest in doing this?  Possibly for a commission?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the author posted an nearly exact answer my question on his website the day after I posted this question.  Whether or not this question prompted the adaptation, I am excited to try it out!

He is calling it "[Zoomable Treemap](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/)".  He also points out a couple other examples on the net.

Thanks, mbostock!